# Angular - How to filter day depending on month in Date of Birth

Tags: angular

I am using Angular-7 to develop a client portal. I want to use select option for date of birth, **but year will not be inclusive**. It will only have month and day. the values in the day field will depend on what month is selected. I currently have this:

client.component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Month</label>
  <select class="form-control pt-1" name="month" [(ngModel)]="data.month">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="name">Month</label>
  <select class="form-control pt-1" name="day" [(ngModel)]="data.day">                
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>21</option>
    <option>22</option>
    <option>23</option>
    <option>24</option>
    <option>25</option>
    <option>26</option>
    <option>27</option>
    <option>28</option>
    <option *ngIf="month != 'February'")>
      29
    </option>
    <option *ngIf="month != 'February'">
      30
    </option>
    <option *ngIf="month == 'January' || month == 'March' || month == 'May' || month == 'July' || month == 'August' || month == 'October' || month == 'December'">
      31
    </option>
 </select>
```

1. How do I achieve my goal?
2. Move it into typescript (client.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the year to account for leap year rules. I'm generating the months and then when the month  or year value updates, the days are generated. The `getDaysInMonth` in a trick to get the right amount of days for a given month and year.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="selectedYear">Year</label>
  <input name="selectedYear" [(ngModel)]="selectedYear" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="selectedMonth">Month</label>
  <select class="form-control pt-1" name="selectedMonth" [(ngModel)]="selectedMonth">
    <option *ngFor="let month of months; let i = index" [value]="i+1">{{month}}</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="selectedDay">Day</label>
  <select name="selectedDay" [(ngModel)]="selectedDay">
    <option *ngFor="let day of days" [value]="day">{{day}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

const getMonth = (idx) => {

  var objDate = new Date();
  objDate.setDate(1);
  objDate.setMonth(idx-1);

  var locale = "en-us",
      month = objDate.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });

    return month;
}



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  months = Array(12).fill(0).map((i,idx) => getMonth(idx + 1));

  selectedYear = 2004;
  selectedMonth = 1;
  selectedDay = 1;

  public get days() {
    const dayCount = this.getDaysInMonth(this.selectedYear, this.selectedMonth);
    return Array(dayCount).fill(0).map((i,idx) => idx +1)
  }

  public getDaysInMonth(year: number, month: number) {
    return 32 - new Date(year, month - 1, 32).getDate();
  }
}
```

You can try it out here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqintz

Comment: What if I don't want the year to appear?

Comment: @ayobamilaye February 2005 has 28 days and February 2004 has 29 days, how would you properly show the days? If you don't care about the leap year days, then you can just hardcode the year to be current year and not have the year field at all.